# Custom UITableViewCell and resizing cell height

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to  create a custom cell for uitableview  with an image at left side  such that the following things happen

1)When the cell is selected , its height is increased , background color is changed and it gets a green color circular button at the position of accessory view

MY APPROACH :- I made a custom uiview such that it contains an imageview at the position of accessory view ,
 and then i did

```
[[table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].contentView addSubview:customCellBackgroundView];
```

but this didnt work , because it hide the cell's text

2)the selected should remain of the same height , such that more than one cell can be selected and the selected cells have larger heights than the unselected ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep a property for each cell that says if it is selected or not. When drawing each cell you check to see if that cell is supose to be selected or not and use 1 of 2 different cell layouts you previously created (one collapsed and the other opened).

So when you click some cell, you change the selected state of that cell and call for a reload of the tableview so that the same cell is now drawn as opened/closed.